# I commented out HTML code, but the control inside it is not disabled

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, comments

I commented out my table in HTML code. Although the table does get removed, the control inside it seems to persist.

```
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="#0066CC"></asp:Label>
    <!--
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="#0066CC"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    -->
</div>
```

When I run my application, visual studio give me an error:

> The ID 'Label1' is already used by another rcontrol.

I do not know why visual studio still checks the control inside the commented out portion of my HTML. Does anybody have any clue on this matter? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably if you change the ID of either label there's no error?

Comment: Yes, if I change the ID of either label from Label1 to Label2, no error occurs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is html comment, not the asp.net server side comment. You should use `<% -- code --%>`

```
<%--
    Commented out HTML/CODE/Markup.  Anything with
    this block will not be parsed/handled by ASP.NET.

    <asp:Calendar runat="server"></asp:Calendar> 

    <%# Eval(“SomeProperty”) %>     
--%>
```

Take a look at [Scott Guthrie's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/09/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Using-Server-Side-Comments-with-ASP.NET-2.0-.aspx)